# How to compare strings matching using Linq?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement an interface in Notification repository:

```
IEnumerable<Notification> INotificationRepository.GetAllNotificationById(int userId)
        {
            return context.Notifications.Where(x => x.receiverUserId.Split(',').Contains(userId.ToString())).ToList();
        }
```

IDE shows error under `x.receiverUserId.Split(',')` and says:

> an expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses
> optional arguments.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a value to the [optional `StringSplitOptions` argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0#system-string-split(system-char-system-stringsplitoptions)):

```cs
...context.Notifications.Where(x => x.receiverUserId.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.None)...
```